# R - How to create a function that accepts a code block as parameter?

Tags: r

I would like to create a function that accepts a code block as a parameter.  I am not sure how to do this in R.  I would like to create a function that has similar behavior to the built-in ***within*** function.

```
data <- within(data, {
  var4 <- var2 + var3
  var5 <- var1 / var2
})
```

I am having trouble finding the ***within*** function definition within the R source code.  Otherwise, I would probably have my answer.

Thanks

Comment: See `within.data.frame` and/or `withing.list`. Whenever a function definition is `UseMethod("foo")`, `methods(foo)` will show you the methods.

Comment: That helps.  Just to clarify for others, I can use 'methods(within)' to find all methods for a generic function.  Then I can use 'edit(within.data.frame)' to see the specific implementation.

Comment: You don't need to call `edit`. Typing `within.data.frame` at the R prompt prints the function definition.

Comment: @NickAllen, you might be interested in reading the "Computing on the language" section of Hadley's wiki: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki

Answer (score 10):

It’s very simple:

```
test <- function(block) {
    cat('before\n')
    rv <- block
    cat('after\n')
    rv
}
```

and to see how it works:

```
test_called <- test({
    cat('bar\n')
    'baz'
})
```

running the latter outputs:

```
before
bar
after
```

and `test_called` has the value `'baz'`

this shows that the block only gets evaluated if you do something with it, instead of immediately when being passed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for.  You just pass the code block (aka expression) to the eval() function.  See *?eval* for more details and variants.

```
foo <- function(expr) {
   result <- eval(expr)
   return(result)
}
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: To provide some context around this, I was trying to create a function that would execute a long-running expression and then cache (aka save) the result so that it didn't need to be re-run. Here is a simplified version of what I ended up creating. I am open to suggestions on how to do this better.

```
cache <- function (cache.name, expr) {

    result <- NULL
    cache.file <- sprintf ("%s/%s.rds", cache.dir, cache.name)

    # has the result already been cached?
    if (file.exists (cache.file)) {
        result <- readRDS(cache.file)

    } else {
        # eval the expression 
        result <- eval(expr)

        # cache the result
        saveRDS (result, cache.file, compress = cache.compress)
    }

    return(result)
}
```

Comment: You'll be a lot better off writing a function that does `expr` and if necessary calling that function:  `function(expr) do.call(expr)` , but you really aren't constructing your code in a good way.

Comment: To provide some context around this, I was trying to create a function that would execute a long-running expression and then cache (aka save) the result so that it didn't need to be re-run.  This is what I ended up creating.  I am open to suggestions on how to do this better.

Comment: cache <- function (cache.name, expr) {
    
        result <- NULL
        cache.file <- sprintf ("%s/%s.rds", cache.dir, cache.name)
    
        # has the result already been cached?
        if (file.exists (cache.file)) {
            result <- readRDS(cache.file)
        
        } else {
        # eval the expression 
        result <- eval(expr)
        
        # cache the result
        logdebug ("Cacheing '%s' as '%s'", cache.name, cache.file)
        saveRDS (result, cache.file, compress = cache.compress)
    }
    
    return(result)
}